# Separate items in cart by size option

Tags: cartthrob, options, size

I am having a problem with my EE CartThrob cart. I have products with "options" for size. In the cart if I add 1 item size Small and 1 item size Medium they get added as the same item with a quantity of 2 and the size option set to Medium. It ignores my first size selection and combines it with the most recent selection.

Is there any way to adjust this so each size is it's own entry in the cart?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of settings under *CartThrob → Settings → Products*:

- Allow items to appear more than once in cart
- Split multiple quantities into single items

These likely need to be adjusted in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Can also happen if your (multi_)add_to_cart form is not correctly passing the options in properly, so check how you're doing that carefully.